# Web page url bar not "shrinking" in mobile safari

Tags: html, css

My website has a wrapper in the body that's used to scroll the inner elements, the problem (I assume) is that mobile safari is not recognizing the scrolling so the url bar is not resizing.  Are there alternatives to this?

```
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

With this setup, mobile safari does not "shrink" the url bar as you scroll like it typically would on other websites.

Comment: Screenshot of current and wanted result please.

Answer (score 0):

For mobile add this meta tag `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />`

or try this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        // Set a timeout...
        setTimeout(function () {
            // Hide the address bar!
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }, 0);
    });
```

Comment: No such luck.  I don't think this post applies when the body is not scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was removing the position: absolute in the wrapper div and replacing it with:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the key is removing `overflow: scroll;`
and u will good to go (i.e. shrinking url bar on scroll)